# Determination of the unique Topology on a set

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have to find the unique Topology on any set $X$ , when the limit of each of the convergent filters in $X$ are known.I can use either of the  results viz. , **1.The intersection of all filters on $X$ converging to $x$ is the neighborhood system of $x $** & **2. $x$  $\in$  $\bar A $ iff  $\exists$ a filter $\mathcal F $ on $X $ such that $\mathcal F $ converges to $x$.**, $\bar A$ is the closure of $A$.

My problem is how can we define convergence of Filters in any set without having a Topology in it  !!! As convergence requires that the neighbourhood system of $x $ to be in the converging filter .

Secondly how to solve the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: for property 2, it should be a filter on $A$, not on $X$ (or it shoud be a filter on $X$ that contains $A$, that also works)

Answer (score 1):

You are given the convergence of the filters and you need to determine what topology gave those convergence points. Look at it this way: The set $X$ has a topology but it is unknown to you. You do know how the filters converge (under this unknown topology). can you now find out what the topology was?

To solve the problem: as you pointed out, The closure of a set can be found by adding all the limit points of filters on that set. The closed sets are the sets that are it's own closure. Putting that in terms of convergence, the collection of closed sets is the following:
$$C = \{A \subseteq X \mid \forall \mathcal{F} (\text{filter on }A): \mathcal{F\rightarrow}x \implies x\in A\}$$

You now know what the closed sets are so you know the topology:
$$\mathcal{T}=\{G \in X \mid X\setminus G \in C\}$$

Comment: Oh! That's a pretty good explanation, cleared  my doubt on the convergence thing.Thanks a lot for the answer@Jens enders.

Comment: @HirenGarai You're welcome! don't forget to accept if your question is answered!

Comment: I have a question about the uniqueness of the Topology, how will I show that ?

Comment: @HirenGarai The argument that I gave shows uniquness, I argue that the topology **has to be** $\mathcal{T}$ (so it can't be anything else)

Comment: Actually what is meant by the uniqueness ? Is it that any element of $\mathcal T$ is not open in any other Topology $\mathcal T_1$ $\neq $ $\mathcal T $ ?

Comment: @HirenGarai No, it means that there is no topology $\mathcal{T_1}\neq \mathcal{T}$ such that every filter has the same points of convergence as the given. Because take a topology $\mathcal{T_1}$ where every filter has the same convergence as the given convergence, then by my argument above $\mathcal{T_1}= \mathcal{T}$

Comment: Okay! I got it. Now I accept it fully. All my doubts are cleared. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the open sets directly (if you know that a certain convergence structure indeed comes from a topology (which need not be the case)):

$O$ is open iff $$\forall x \in O: \forall \mathcal{F} : (\mathcal{F} \to x) \implies O \in \mathcal{F}$$

This holds because $O$ should be a neighbourhood for all of its points, and a filter converges to a point, iff it contains all its neighbourhoods (so $O$ as well).

If we are given a relation $R$ between filters on $X$ and points of $X$, that tells us what converges to what : $(\mathcal{F}, x) \in R$ is then written as $\mathcal{F} \to x$, and we know that this is a topological convergence then the above definition gives us the (unique) original topology this is a convergence of.

Comment: I didn't get your answer's last paragraph, will you explain ? @HennoBrandsma. It is ok till $\mathcal F $ $\rightarrow $  $x$. After that I didn't make out

Comment: @HirenGarai I mean that not all such relations need to come from a topology. But for the ones that obey some simple axioms, we can define a topology with this definition on a "convergence space". If the convergence came from some topology, we get that same topology back with this definition.