# If every convergent net in a space is eventually constant then the space is Discrete.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, nets

The question I am asking is actually I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376293/characterization-of-a-topological-space-in-terms-of-convergence-of-nets-in-it).

I have solved  the problem in the following way:

**Proof**: 
We have every convergent net in $X$ to be eventually constant....$(1)$

We have to show that the Topology with respect to which the nets are convergent on $X$ is *Discrete* i.e every singleton is open.

Let us define $\mathcal T=\{G\subset X\,:\,\text{ No  net in $X\setminus G$ converges in $G$}\}$.

Then obviously $\mathcal T$ is a topology on $X$.
Now from the construction of $\mathcal T$, and the hypothesis $(1)$ we can say that no net in $X\setminus\{x\}$ can converge in $\{x\}$,
(because if any net from $X\setminus\{x\}$ converges to {$x$} then $S$ is eventually equal to $x$, hence $S$ can't be in $X\setminus\{x\}$) 
**i.e** to say that $\{x\}$ is open.
Hence $\mathcal T$ is **Discrete**.

Is my proof okay ? Am I missing something ? If yes then please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Why is it true that $\emptyset\in\mathcal T$?

Comment: No net in $X$ $-$ $\emptyset$ i.e in $X$ can converge in $\emptyset$.

Comment: Right. I misunderstood the definition of $\mathcal T$. Please use $\setminus$ instead of $-$ when working with sets.

Comment: Assuming that $\mathcal T$ is a topology, it looks like all that you proved was that it's the discrete topology. How do you deduce from that that the original topology is discrete?

Comment: Ok sir..Is my proof ok ?

Comment: I think the Topology $\mathcal T $ is uniquely determined by the characterization. I think I have to show that the Topology with respect to which every convergent net is eventually constant is the discrete one and here I have shown this. Its  like that I am given a Topological Space in which I know that every convergent net is eventually constant,but I don't know the Topology,so I constructed the Topology $\mathcal T$ ,and this is the only Topology with respect to which the convergent nets are eventually constant .

Comment: If $\mathcal T$ is indeed a topology or, more generally, if it is closed under arbitrary unions, then your proof is indeed correct. But you did not prove that $\mathcal T$ is indeed a topology.

Comment: Oh ! I see..Let me show it then.

Comment: Let me show that finite intersection of 2 elements of $\mathcal T$ is in it.If not then there is a net $\mathscr S$ in the complement of their intersection which converge to their intersection,but then $\mathscr S$ is either in the complement of both the 2 sets or atleast in the complement of 1 set,and in both case we arrive at a contradiction(as the net $\mathscr S$ converge to their intersection so it converges to both the sets,which cannot happen).So their finite intersection must be in $\mathcal T$.Hence by induction we get the result.

Comment: Why is it not possible that some elements of $\mathcal S$ belong to the complemento of the first set while other elements of $\mathcal S$ belong to the complement of the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by 'some' here ? How much ? If some elements are in the complement of one and some in the other's complement,then also $\mathscr S$ is a net in both the complement I think..

Comment: What I meant is the some elements of $\mathscr S$ in the complement of one set again forms a net and is convergent.

Comment: You can start with a convergence notion (satisfying some axioms) and indeed define a topology this way. But one requires proof to see that *if* the convergence notion originally came from a topology ,that this defined topology is indeed the original one.

Comment: Have a look https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2378875/384535.. I got the idea came from here and I thought they are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true necessarily that $(x_i) \to x$ and the net is eventually constant than that constant must be $x$. So your proposed proof does not work as it stands.

E.g. in the space $X= \{0,1,2\}$ with open sets $\{\emptyset, \{1,2\}, X\}$ the constant net with only the value $2$ converges to $1$ and $0$ as well...

Note that this is a "local counterexample" (Lakatos' term), it shows we need a stronger assumption for the proof you propose to work:

(1) For every net $(x_i)_i$ that converges to some $x \in X$, there is some $i_0 \in I$ such that for all $i \ge i_0$: $x_i = x$ (so not just constant but constant *with constant value the limit*, which is stricter, but indeed holds in discrete spaces).

Comment: But I have said that the net is eventually constant,not a constant...still I am wrong ?

Comment: @HirenGarai you have to strengthen it to "eventually constant **and** with value = limit", otherwise you cannot show that singletons are open in your way.

Comment: But if a convergent net is eventually constant and equal to $x$ say then will it not be case that it's limit is $x $ ?

Comment: @HirenGarai no, see my example.limits are not unique.

Comment: I got you sir !! I haven't thought that deep.Thanks for pointing me..So if every convergent net is eventually constant and  equal to it's limit,then the space is Discrete ?

Comment: @HirenGarai yes, then your proof works.

Comment: Thank you sir..@HennoBrandsma.